# Global scss variables with reactjs and webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, global-variables

I am working with reactjs and webpack, and i am trying to make global variables of sass so i can use them any where without import them. But i didn't succeed , i had added the file to webpack but always the same problem. Even the other solution on stackoverflow didn't work with me, can any one help please ?

here is my index.scss :

```
@import "../public/scss/variables";
@import "../public/scss/mixin";
```

here is my variables.scss file:

```
$blueColor: #049DD6;
$darkBlueColor: #08536A;
$garyColor: #DFEFEF;
$darkGaryColor: #D5bbDE;
$pinkColor:#F05389;
$greenColor:#1DCD5A;
$redColor:#F60ELE;
$errorColor:#AAG601;
```

and here is the simple login.scss where i tried to access one of my variable but it show my variable undefined:

```
.left-panel {
    background-color: $blueColor;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the import using the extension:

```
    @import "../public/scss/variables.scss";
```

Comment: This is not a good practice... imagine i ll write 100 pages of scss... no i can't

Answer (score 0):

Check if your loader options in your webpack module rules are correct.

```
 {
            test: [/\.scss$/, /\.css/],
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
              Object.assign(
                {
                  fallback: {
                    loader: require.resolve('style-loader')
                  },
                  use: [
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('css-loader')
                    },
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
                    },
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('json-sass-mixin-loader')
                    },
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('sass-resources-loader'),
                      options: {
                        resources: [
                          'path/to/mixins/*.scss',
                          'path/to/variables.scss']
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader')
                    },
                  ],
                },
              )
            ),

          }
```

Comment: Here is how i changed my webpack, [https://ibb.co/C08c5Gx] but now i have this error :
**Something wrong with provided resources.
      Make sure 'options.resources' is String or Array of Strings.**

Comment: Can you answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an absolute path for the **options.resources** array. Example:

```
resources: [
 path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles/variables.scss')
]
```

or

```
resources: [
 './src/styles/variables.scss'
]
```

Both should work